# Tree of widgets in WxWidgets

Tags: tree, widget, wxpython, wxwidgets

I would like to code a tree of widgets similar to the left panel of the Empire XPU / Empire XCCel interface (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPB3a.jpg) using wxWidgets (more precisely its wxPython binding).

How to implement this?

Comment: take a look at the wxWidgets `widgets` sample. It is in C++, but its easily translatable to wxPython.

Comment: There's nothing like this available out of the box. The closest existing control is [wxPropertyGrid](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_property_grid.html).  If you want a control exactly like the one in that picture, you'll have to make it yourself. You can start with something like [wxVListBox](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_v_list_box.html) and override its OnDrawItem method to draw the controls and tree lines.

Comment: Of course there is in wxPython: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl.CustomTreeCtrl.html#wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl.CustomTreeCtrl

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The wxPython CustomTreeCtrl is exactly what I need.